# Symfony 2 get json request

Tags: json, api, symfony, request

I have an endpoint which is receiving updates from a service for my subscribers to my app (using a 3rd party api). These are getting sent to me as a post. I don't know how to get the content I've tried few things).

this is what's being received each files has unique generated number

**UPLOADED FILES
updates: update1389874969000.json (application/json)**

This code I've tried -

```
          $request = $this->getRequest(); 

          $request->request->get('updates');
```

// don't get an error but don't get any data
or

```
 $request = $this->getRequest(); 

 $request->files->get('updates');
get '/tmp/php0oJ2oP' which doesn't mean anything to me
```

Any ideas how to parse this json data, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{   
    $personData = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
```

Ok.  So your are not receiving json as content.  Instead, a json file is being uploaded.

The /tmp/php0oJ2oP that you got is actually the path to your uploaded file.  You can read and convert to a php array with

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('/tmp/php0oJ2oP'),true);
```

Of course you will get a different tmp path for each upload so pull the path from the request.

More info on file uploads can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

But all you really need is the tmp path.

Comment: That doesn't give me any data.  In standard PHP they suggest $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['updates']['tmp_name']  how would I do that in symfony2 ?  thanks